# Is there a simpler way to check radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm new to coding and learning HTML as well as JavaScript. I wrote a set of radio buttons in HTML so that you could toggle an option and click the submit button, and it would use JS to display the option you chose below. The code works fine, however:

1. The code is quite clunky, I'm positive there must be a much more effective way of writing this code.
2. I didn't use the form tag, should I? I'm still not entirely sure what form does other than I know it's used to collect data somehow

```js
var x;

function displayText() {
  if (document.getElementById("lsd").checked === true) {
    x = document.getElementById("lsd").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
  } else if (document.getElementById("shrooms").checked === true) {
    x = document.getElementById("shrooms").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
  } else if (document.getElementById("dmt").checked === true) {
    x = document.getElementById("dmt").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
  } else if (document.getElementById("peyote").checked === true) {
    x = document.getElementById("peyote").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
  } else if (document.getElementById("toad").checked === true) {
    x = document.getElementById("toad").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>What's your preferred psychedelic substance?</p>
<input type="radio" id="lsd" name="drugs" value="lsd">
<label for="lsd">LSD</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="shrooms" name="drugs" value="shrooms">
<label for="shrooms">Magic Mushrooms/psilocybin</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="dmt" name="drugs" value="dmt">
<label for="dmt">DMT</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="peyote" name="drugs" value="peyote">
<label for="peyote">Peyote</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="toad" name="drugs" value="toad">
<label for="toad">The Toad/5-MeO-DMT</label>
<br>
<button onclick="displayText()">Submit!</button>
<p>
  User's favorite drug is: <span id="output"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more powerful selector can select the element you want without manually checking each

```js
function displayText() {
  const selected = document.querySelector("[name='drugs']:checked");
   
  const value = selected ? selected.value :null;

  document.getElementById("output").innerText = value;
}
```

```html
<p>What's your preferred psychedelic substance?</p>
<input type="radio" id="lsd" name="drugs" value="lsd">
<label for="lsd">LSD</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="shrooms" name="drugs" value="shrooms">
<label for="shrooms">Magic Mushrooms/psilocybin</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="dmt" name="drugs" value="dmt">
<label for="dmt">DMT</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="peyote" name="drugs" value="peyote">
<label for="peyote">Peyote</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="toad" name="drugs" value="toad">
<label for="toad">The Toad/5-MeO-DMT</label>
<br>
<button onclick="displayText()">Submit!</button>
<p>
  User's favorite drug is: <span id="output"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it like this:
You can paste it directly in HTML file and test.
I would not recommend this for prod but for learning purposes it is good.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
        name="viewport">
  <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>What's your preferred psychedelic substance?</p>
<form id="form">

</form>

<button onclick="displayText()">Submit!</button>
<p>
  User's favorite drug is: <span id="output"></span>
</p>
</body>
<script>
  const drugs = {
    "lsd": "LSD",
    "shrooms": "Magic Mushrooms/psilocybin",
    "dmt": "DMT",
    "peyote": "Peyote",
    "toad": "The Toad/5-MeO-DMT"
  };

  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  for (const key in drugs) {
    form.innerHTML += `
  <label style="display: block" for="lsd">
    <input type="radio" id="${key}" name="drugs" value="${key}">
    ${drugs[key]}
  </label>`;
  }

  function displayText() {
    const drugs = document.getElementsByName("drugs");
    for (let i = 0; i < drugs.length; i++) {
      if (drugs[i].checked) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = drugs[i].value;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```